# How to insert data to a temp table from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
INSERT INTO #Temp (id, id2, a, b) 
SELECT id, id2, a, b 
FROM SomeOneTable
```

We usually get the data from one table, How do we insert the data on temp table if (`id` and `a`) fields are from a separate table and  (`id2` and `b`) are from another table. I want all the 4 fields to be in one Temp table.

Comment: Do a JOIN (in the SELECT part on your INSERT.)

Comment: Use join, cross joins, depending on logic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `INNER JOIN` for example

```
INSERT INTO #Temp (id, id2, a, b)
SELECT TABLE_A.ID, TABLE_B.ID2, TABLE_A.A, TABLE_B.B
FROM TABLE_A INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.[primary_key] = TABLE_B.[foreign_key]
```

Comment: I'll mark as soon as the timer is done: it says I can mark it in 6 minutes

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
    INSERT INTO #Temp (id, id2, a, b) 
    SELECT id, id2, a, b 
    FROM SomeOneTable a inner join someonetable2 b on a.id=b.id2
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Using Inner join :
Assume you have two table: Table1 and Table2

```
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE (id, id2, a, b)

SELECT B.ID, C.ID2 , B.A, C.B FROM TABLE1 AS B , TABLE2 AS C
```